# how to see the implemented code of a function of a module in haskell?

Tags: haskell, module, functional-programming

I am a newbie to Haskell and I know The Haskell standard library is split into `modules`, each of them contains `functions` and `types` that are somehow related and serve some common purpose. I would like to see the implementation(code) of those library functions.where can I see that ? is there any command in `ghci` so that I can see the implementation or provide me any resources to learn about modules.
Thank you

Comment: Check it out from Hackage. For example this is [Data.Vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html) package. Every function, instance or data definition explained also includes a #source link at the rightmost of the corresponding line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the most convenient way to do it, is use [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map). You can for instance inspect the `map` function, by clicking [`Source`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#map) on the right side of the function signature. This then will show the highlighted code fragment. For instance:

> ```
> map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
> {-# NOINLINE [0] map #-}
>   -- We want the RULEs "map" and "map/coerce" to fire first.
>   -- map is recursive, so won't inline anyway,
>   -- but saying so is more explicit, and silences warnings
> map _ []     = []
> map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
> ```

You can also use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to search functions by name or signature, and by clicking the results, you will be redirected to the relevant hackage page.